# Inserting image in DXF File with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, dxf

I am using a DXFwrite library to create a DXF File using a plugin in QGIS. I tried to search in the official documentation of this library about adding or insert an image file into the DXF.

Manually is possible in autocad, but using pyqgis and Dxfwrite library, i didn’t find it